# Injecting python code into TCP socket server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, code-injection

I am stuck in this task for a question I'm solving to do with penetration testing, we are given a simple TCP web server, and we are to connect to it and give two values, if they match in the end, we get the flag, we are also given a snippet of the server code. I have tried everything I know to get flag. Here's the code:

```
clientsock.send("Welcome to Maths_Server 1.0\n")
try:
    clientsock.send("Enter the first number, so I can EVALuate it:\n")
    firstNum = eval(clientsock.recv(1024))
    firstNum = firstNum + firstNum + ord(flag[4]) + ord(flag[8]) + ord(flag[5])
    clientsock.send("Enter the second number, so I can EVALuate it:\n")
    secondNum = eval(clientsock.recv(1024))
    if secondNum == firstNum:
        clientsock.send("The flag is: " + flag + "\n")
        firstNum = 0
        secondNum = 0
except:
    pass

clientsock.close()
```

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of times you can try?

Comment: Nevermind. You don't need more than one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just send the string `firstNum` as the second message. Then you will succeed no matter what you used as value for firstNum initially:

```
    secondNum = eval(clientsock.recv(1024))
->  secondNum = eval("firstNum")
->  secondNum = ... value of firstNum
```

This can easily done with telnet

```
$ telnet services.cyberprotection.agency 3166
Welcome to Maths_Server 1.0
Enter the first number, so I can EVALuate it:
10
Enter the second number, so I can EVALuate it:
firstNum
The flag is: .... (try yourself)...
```

Another possibility is that you just send the string `clientsock.send(flag)` as the first number which immediately will send you the value of flag back. Note that this does not work with the test server, so I guess that the source code is slightly different and does not simply execute any kind of code given by a remote user but only if it matches the expectations of the task you got. But it works with my test installation of the given code.

Which hopefully leads you to the conclusion that one should never ever just eval unsanitized user input.

Comment: ... I can't believe I didn't think of that, I guess I was stressed out by the other 20+ problems I have to do today, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the numbers are converted from string to "number" using `eval`. This means that you do not need to pass in a number, just something that evaluates as one. Since `eval` uses local variables, you can feed in the string `-0.5 * (ord(flag[4]) + ord(flag[8]) + ord(flag[5]))` for `firstNum`, which will make the next line set `firstNum` to zero. Then you can pass literal `0` for `secondNum` and get `flags`.

You may need to pad your string to 1024 characters. I would do something like `output.center(1024, ' ')`.

Comment: Doesn't work, it doesn't ask me for a second number then it closes the connection, maybe that happens because it throws an exception and it has
except:
    pass
or maybe it is due to me connect via nc on the terminal? I'm not sure

Comment: Is there a website or something that has instructions? I don't want to randomly just ping a server I am not familiar with.

Comment: My solution is theoretically correct, but the snippet is clearly incomplete. Stephen's aswer is very much correct though.